# Leaflet legend with subtitles for grouped values

Tags: css, r, legend, r-leaflet, legend-properties

Is there a way to add subtitles to leaflet legends? The following example produces a functioning legend. However, is there a way to combine the subgroups to the same legend?

I could imagine this could be solved by injecting custom CSS-code to the legend by the `className` parameter (default `className = "info legend"`). But I'm a complete novice to CSS.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.1.1/topics/addLegend

Helpful might as well be this work, done for the spacing to the NA-class (https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/615#issuecomment-656035992)

To illustrate what I would like to have I created different legend entries, but they are not properly connected.

```
library(leaflet)
colors <- colorFactor(palette="viridis",
                      domain=gadmCHE@data$NAME_1, na.color="transparent")

Deutsch <- gadmCHE[c(1:6,9:12,14:20,22,25:26),]
Italienisch <- gadmCHE[c(21),]
Französisch <- gadmCHE[-c(1:6,9:12,14:22,25:26),]

gadmCHE %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~colors(NAME_1), fillOpacity = 1) %>%
  addLegend(position = "topright", pal = colors, values = Deutsch@data$NAME_1, title = "Deutsch")%>%
  addLegend(position = "topright", pal = colors, values = Italienisch@data$NAME_1, title = "Italiensch")%>%
  addLegend(position = "topright", pal = colors, values = Französisch@data$NAME_1, title = "Französisch")
```

[image: slightly more complex plot]

I actually would need to replicate the following. Please bear with me as

- I'm aware it would be better to shorten the legend entries, but that has quite some legacy attached to it. It is unlikely I'll be successful on that.
- The attribution of the Cantons to different language regions is not... correct.
- It further is not exactly what I would like to show, as in my case, the whole legend entry cannot be made shorter (i.e. a, Senkrecht durchwaschene Böden, Normal durchlässig, sehr tiefgründig)

[image]